# Formulating inequality constraints in NLOPTR's ISRES algorithm

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nlopt

I got stuck while applying NLOPTR's ISRES algorithm to a nonlinear problem with inequality constraints. I formulated it like this:

```
library(nloptr)
fn <- function(x) {
(x[1]-10)^2 + 5*(x[2]-12)^2 + x[3]^4 + 3*(x[4]-11)^2 + 10*x[5]^6 + 7*x[6]^2 + x[7]^4 - 4*x[6]*x[7] - 10*x[6] - 8*x[7]
}

hin <- function(x) {
h <- numeric(4)
h[1] <- 127 - 2*x[1]^2 - 3*x[2]^4 - x[3] - 4*x[4]^2 - 5*x[5]
h[2] <- 282 - 7*x[1] - 3*x[2] - 10*x[3]^2 - x[4] + x[5]
h[3] <- 196 - 23*x[1] - x[2]^2 - 6*x[6]^2 + 8*x[7]
h[4] <- -4*x[1]^2 - x[2]^2 + 3*x[1]*x[2] -2*x[3]^2 - 5*x[6] +11*x[7]
return(h)
}

x0 <- c(1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1)

isres(x0 = x0, fn = fn, hin = hin)
```

I get a message which says "Error in match(hin): argument "table" is missing, with no default"

I guess I'm not doing something right with the inequality constraints. Can you please tell me how to solve this? Many Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really an answer. But I currently cannot comment.

I think the problem are **not** your constraints but the function `isres`. If you take a look into the code of the function (just type `isres` into your console), the start looks like this:

```
function (x0, fn, lower, upper, hin = NULL, heq = NULL, maxeval = 10000, 
          pop.size = 20 * (length(x0) + 1), xtol_rel = 1e-06, nl.info = FALSE, 
          ...) 
{
  opts <- list()
  opts$maxeval <- maxeval
  opts$xtol_rel <- xtol_rel
  opts$population <- pop.size
  opts$algorithm <- "NLOPT_GN_ISRES"
  fun <- match.fun(fn)
  fn <- function(x) fun(x, ...)
  if (!is.null(hin)) {
    .hin <- match(hin)
    hin <- function(x) (-1) * .hin(x)
  } 
...
```

Now, please note the line `.hin <- match(hin)`. The match function is base `R` and should take two arguments, i.e.: `x` and `table` as it executes `x %in% table` (check `?match` in the `R` documentation for more info). But, `isres` does not provide a table to the function.

As it stands know you have 3 options to solve your problem:

- (I) Using `nloptr` directly with the algorithm `"NLOPT_GN_ISRES"`.
- (II) The mantainer of the package told me that the bug is probably allready known. Thus, you are likely fine if you use the developement package on [github](https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr) instead of the CRAN version. **Note that the package did not compile on my computer**
- (III) Wait until the bug is fixed. Which should be pretty soon, as they now know about the problem.

Comment: I think the writer of the `isres` function meant `match.call` rather than `match`.

Comment: Ah. Very insightful. I will write a mail to the maintainer of the package.

Comment: @Ahnaf Please do not forget to mark my question as answered if you think it is and give me feedback if you think it is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel and Grothendieck! Your insightful answers were really helpful.